# Function and keyword argument

Tags: python, function, while-loop, keyword-argument

Why is my code not working? I am following UDEMY's 100 days of code and it is essentially the same as the instructor but I wanted to have keyword named arguments. First of all it's not printing the correct turn_left after each turn and it's not stopping the game.

```
from random import randint

EASY_LEVEL_TURNS = 10
HARD_LEVEL_TURNS = 5


def check_answer(user_guess, correct_answer, tracking_turns):
    """
    Checks answer with guess.
    """
    if user_guess > correct_answer:
        print("Too high")
        return tracking_turns - 1
    elif user_guess < correct_answer:
        print("Too low")
        return tracking_turns - 1
    elif user_guess == correct_answer:
        print(f"Right the answer is {correct_answer}")


def set_difficulty(game_level):
    """
    Sets game difficulty
    """
    if game_level == "easy":
        return EASY_LEVEL_TURNS
    elif game_level == "hard":
        return HARD_LEVEL_TURNS


def game():
    """
    Setting up the game
    """
    guess = 0

    answer = randint(1, 100)
    print("Welcome to the number guessing game!")
    print("I am thinking of a number between 1 to 100")

    level = input("How difficult would you like the game to be? Easy or Hard ").lower()
    turn_left = set_difficulty(game_level=level)

    while guess != answer:
        print(f"You have {turn_left} attempts to guess the answer.")

        guess = int(input("What is your guess? "))
        answer_checked = check_answer(user_guess=guess, correct_answer=answer, 
                                      tracking_turns=turn_left)

        if turn_left == 0:
            print("You have ran out of terms")
            return


game()
```

Comment: You are never decrementing `turn_left` in your `game` function.

Comment: You assign the result of `check_answer` (which sometimes, but not always, returns an updated `tracking_turns`/`turn_left` value) to `answer_checked`, but don't do anything to update `turn_left`.

Comment: `answer_checked =` should be `turn_left =`

Comment: I am decrementing turn_left on check_answer function

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your game function like this, mainly by updating the turn_left value and setting the end-of-function condition

```
def game():
    """
    Setting up the game
    """
    guess = 0

    answer = randint(1, 100)
    print("Welcome to the number guessing game!")
    print("I am thinking of a number between 1 to 100")

    level = input("How difficult would you like the game to be? Easy or Hard ").lower()
    turn_left = set_difficulty(game_level=level)

    while guess != answer:
        print(f"You have {turn_left} attempts to guess the answer.")

        guess = int(input("What is your guess? "))
        turn_left = check_answer(user_guess=guess, correct_answer=answer,
                                      tracking_turns=turn_left)

        if turn_left == 0:
            print("You have ran out of terms")
            return
        elif not turn_left:
            return
```